# Question about poles of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Suppose I have a function $f(z)$ with a pole of order $m$ at $z=0$. Then I know that $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} z^m f(z)$ is finite. How can I then show that $\lim\limits_{z \to 0} z^{2m}f(z^2)$ is also finite?

Comment: maybe  $z^{2*m}=z^m*z^m $ ?  and  limit of product is  product of limits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u:=z^2$. Then the limit is equivalent to $\lim_{u\rightarrow 0}u^mf(m)$.

Why it's equivalent: if $\lim_{z\rightarrow a}g(z)$ exists, then it must be the same along any subsequence $z_i$.